# Javascript, can I change this to a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a navigation bar and have it working. I want to however change my writing. There is repetitive code that looks like this:

```
$("nav span").mouseover(function(){
var currentColor = $("#" +$(this).attr("data-loc")).css("backgroundColor");
var currentPos = $(this).position().left;

if ($(this).attr("data-loc") === "home"){
    $("#hoverstyle").animate({"left":currentPos},150);
    $("#hoverstyle").css("backgroundColor",currentColor);
    $("#hoverstyle").css({width:$(this).width()});

}
else if($(this).attr("data-loc") === "writer"){
    $("#hoverstyle").animate({"left":currentPos},150);
    $("#hoverstyle").css("backgroundColor",currentColor);
    $("#hoverstyle").css({width:$(this).width()});
}
else if($(this).attr("data-loc") === "historian"){
    $("#hoverstyle").animate({"left":currentPos},150);
    $("#hoverstyle").css("backgroundColor",currentColor);
    $("#hoverstyle").css({width:$(this).width()});

}
else if($(this).attr("data-loc") === "teacher"){
    $("#hoverstyle").animate({"left":currentPos},150);
    $("#hoverstyle").css("backgroundColor",currentColor);
    $("#hoverstyle").css({width:$(this).width()});

}
else if($(this).attr("data-loc") === "fencing"){
    $("#hoverstyle").animate({"left":currentPos},150);
    $("#hoverstyle").css("backgroundColor",currentColor);
    $("#hoverstyle").css({width:$(this).width()});

}
});
```

But I can't figure out how to make it better, I was thinking into making it a loop, but I can't figure it out -.-.. Please help!

Comment: Why aren't you using `switch`?

Comment: Why are you using an `if`/`else if`? You're doing the *same thing* in every eventuality.

Comment: why have you added if else when you are not doing anything separate in them

Comment: Comments made me laugh

Comment: Why all the downvotes? An attempt is shown, and the problem with the attempt is clearly stated.  Inexperience or lack of knowledge alone does not mean the question is a bad one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would make an array of valid loc values, and then see if the element has a value in that array.

```
var locs = ['home', 'writer', 'historian', 'teacher', 'fencing'];

var thisLoc = $(this).attr('data-loc');
if (locs.indexOf(thisLoc) > -1) {
  //do stuff
}
```

Array's `indexOf` method returns the index of the item if it was found in the array.  Otherwise it returns `-1`.  So if you more that `-1` you know that the `data-loc` value is in your array and you can take an action.

---

You can also cleanup your jQuery manipulations by reusing the `$('#hoverstyle')` object, this is called chaining. jQuery's methods usually return the jQuery object so that you can chain calls without finding the object again.  And you can combine your `css()` call to one call that passes in an object with two properties.

```
$("#hoverstyle")
    .animate({"left":currentPos},150)
    .css({
        backgroundColor: currentColor,
        width:$(this).width()
    });
```

Comment: **+1** Very good idea, and in your next edit you actually *explained* why it works

Comment: Note that `Array.prototype.indexOf` is not supported by IE<=8.

Comment: If you need to support IE <= 8, polyfill it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill

Answer (score 3):

Switch statement ?

```
switch ($(this).attr("data-loc"))
{
   case "home":
   case "writer":
   case "historian": 
   case "teacher":
   case "fencing":
       $("#hoverstyle").animate({"left":currentPos},150);
       $("#hoverstyle").css("backgroundColor",currentColor);
       $("#hoverstyle").css({width:$(this).width()});
       break;
   default: 
       break;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to select the same element three times, why are you not chaining those methods?

Comment: **+1** I have a problem with posting a comment as an answer, I'm always afraid it's incorrect :P

Comment: Same, but I cannot comment all the time, not enough reputation, so I answer :/